# Как с помощью регулярного выражения отделить символы с большой буквой, добавив пробел?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Как можно обработать текст, что если приходит

```
ЭтоОченьДлинныйТекстВообщеБезПробелов ИТутБылПробел
```

Как эту строку разделить по правилу, что б перед большой буквой поставился пробел, но только если спереди пробела не было и это не первый символ строки?
Что б получить

```
Это Очень Длинный Текст Вообще Без Пробелов И Тут Был Пробел
```

Comment: Было бы неплохо если бы вы предоставили свои попытки решения.

Comment: @ΝNL993 
transform(text: string): string {
  return text.replace(/(?<=\S)(?=[А-ЯЁ])/g, " ").replace(/_/g, " ");
}

Спасибо, Та если бы я сразу знал, то не задавал бы вопрос)))) апгрейдил чуть, добавив ещё удаление символа _

Comment: Не за что :) Просто по правилам StackOverflow надо обязательно предоставлять попытки решения, правильные они или нет, разницы не имеет, главное что вы пытались решить её сами.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно вот так?

```js
function solution(str) {
  return str.replace(/[А-ЯЁ]/g, (m, i) =>
    i === 0 || str[i - 1] === ' '
      ? m
      : ' ' + m
  )
}

function test(current, expected) {
  let changed = solution(current)
  console.log(changed, '\nPASSED?', changed === expected)
}

test(
  'ЭтоОченьДлинныйТекстВообщеБезПробелов ИТутБылПробел',
  'Это Очень Длинный Текст Вообще Без Пробелов И Тут Был Пробел'
)

test(
  'ИТутБылПробелЁМоё',
  'И Тут Был Пробел Ё Моё'
)
```

Comment: Пробуйте строку "ИТутБылПробелЁМоё'"

Comment: Поправил, проверяйте :)

Answer (score 2):

Где 2, там и 3

```js
text = 'ЭтоОченьДлинныйТекстВообщеБезПробелов ИТутБылПробел';
console.log(text.replace(/(?<!^|\s)([А-ЯЁ])/g,' $1'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let str = 'ЭтоОченьДлинныйТекстВообщеБезПробелов ИТутБылПробел';
console.log(str.replace(/(?<!\s)[\А-\Я]/g, ' $&').trim());
```

Comment: Пробуйте строку "ИТутБылПробелЁМоё'"